# .bowerrc option to make bower install assume --save

Tags: node.js, installation, package, bower, bower-install

I noticed [here](https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1074) that there was some work towards adding a `.bowerrc` option to make bower install automatically `--save`.

After searching and looking in the docs I couldn't find a way to use it. After browsing the source of both bower and bower-config I couldn't find any other reference to it. Does anyone know if this is implemented and can be used somehow, or if it's still work in progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it comes from here:

https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1040

but it's in progress, they've planned it for version 2.0

Comment: Awesome! Now it's just a matter of waiting. Thanks!